Wordpress - How to place my custom nav menu in the sites footer, from my plugin
I've created a plugin for a custom mobile menu on my site.
Everything works as I'd like, except I can't work out how to place the menu on my site from within my plugin files, rather than by adding it to my sites footer.php.
Currently to get it to display I'm added the following to my child theme footer.php:
<?php 
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location'=>'custom-mobile-menu', 'container_class'=>'jape-menu-class' ) );
?>

Is there a guide anywhere that will tell me to place this from within my plugin?
I've tried searching for an answer, but everything I can find is using a child theme.
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Turns out I didn't need to be as specific with the placement as I thought, this did the trick:
function jape_footer_scripts()
{
    echo wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location'=>'custom-mobile-menu', 'container_class'=>'jape-menu-class' ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'jape_footer_scripts' ); 

